# Public licensing and GNU

Tags: licensing, gnu

I have been reading this post on the codeigniter forum, http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/174928/ and it has me thinking.Suppose i come up with a software and i take some code licensed under one the public licenses, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical

My software becomes wildly popular and profitable but,it turns out i forgot to include the license agreement for instance, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html

Has the author of the original works got any right to sue me for copyright infringement for what he/she offered for free in the first place?.Should these licenses be taken seriously?

Comment: Where's the "public" in **open source** licences? Well, MIT ends up being as close to public domain as you'll get, but otherwise...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IANAL, TINLA, ask a lawyer.

My opinion:

You don't technically have to *bundle* the license text with your software, but you are required to somehow inform people who obtain the binaries of their rights under the original license, and where they may obtain a copy of said license.  And you must fulfill your obligations under said license.  So if it's the GPL and a customer asks you for the source code, you are legally obligated to provide it to them.

And yes, you should take such licenses seriously -- big companies do, and **the licenses are legal documents** and constitute an agreement between you and the original licensor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the author is in full legal right to sue you as most (if not all) open source license agreements specify that the software is provided to you under certain conditions, one of which is that the licensing arrangement isn't altered.

By distributing without the license, you basically alter the licensing arrangement where the previous license cannot be accepted.  The author explicitly reserves the right to alter the licensing agreement, under open source they do not grant you the right to re-license their software under other agreements.

Should you have already distributed the software without distributing the license, then you are using software without agreeing to the license, which means you copied the software without permission to do so.  Technically you are in copyright violation.

When in doubt, contact a lawyer.  To reduce damages and show good will, fix the problem as soon as humanly possible.  Some organizations don't press the matter if you quickly comply, even though it is still in their right to sue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's serious and you could be liable to legal action from the [Free Software Foundation](http://www.fsf.org/). (I have been audited by them - I didn't do anything illegal but they were doing random checks). It's a valuable service .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and yes. Copyright has nothing to do with whether the copy of the copyright work is paid for or not, and there is an increasing amount of case law that demonstrate these licences are enforceable. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Software_Foundation#GPL_enforcement) for what has happened for one of the licences (GPL)

You are using (and benefiting from) the work of others. The owners of that work get to decide what can be done about it.

But this legal advice is worth what you paid for it (nothing). Consult a lawyer to be sure

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.